# Make SVG Nodes Be Clickable Buttons in Angular app

Tags: angularjs, svg

I created a keyboard-like object in Inkscape as an SVG file. In my AngularJS application, I added the SVG file as an `<object>`. I'd like the buttons on my keyboard (which are `<rect>` nodes with text labels) to be clickable and trigger a click method in my controller. I'm not sure how to wire this up. Can someone explain how I can do this (or if it's even possible)?

Sample SVG (please remember, this is an svg file, imported as an `<object>`): `<rect ry="17.928572" y="534.34534" x="293.02008" height="81.428596" width="82.85714" id="btn_EXIT" style="fill:#4d4d4d;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:3;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;filter:url(#filter8780-54)" ng-click="doExit()"/>`

MainCtrl.js: `$scope.doExit = function() { // do exit... }`

Comment: Sounds like an interesting question. Could you maybe also provide the svg keyboard graphics (or a simple test graphics) and some small AngularJS example file?

Comment: I don't really know what you want @Trilarion. I edited my post, with some code that I think illustrates what I'm trying to do. I don't know if ng-click can be a property of a `rect`. But I need some way to wire that object up to a function in the controller.